# Hypothesis test for comparing 6 means to find the greatest result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have six groups of continuous data, each representing the performance of a computer program, with which I want to compare the means to find if the one with the greatest performance is such by a statistically significant margin. Is there any standard way to do this other than a series of t-tests treating a different group as the control in each case? Additionally, how would I formulate a hypothesis for this in a clear way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do is an analysis of variance (ANOVA) or linear regression model. You could then:

- Do the ANOVA or regression, then look at the five comparisons, comparing the top group with to the other five, doing some type of p-value adjustment.
- Specify a contrast a priori, where you compare one group to the other five.

For a reference, check out: *Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences* by Cohen, Cohen, West, & Aiken (2003), Chapter 8.